# Google drive not working

Tags: drive, google, grive

grive-tools and google-drive-ocamlfuse are not more working...does someone know another free (better open source) service for google account in ubuntu?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://www.insynchq.com/ costs a little bit but works stable.

or [drive](https://github.com/rakyll/drive)